# how to populate a dropdown menu with array in typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown menu I my html file, and I have an array of objects in my typescript file that I get using an API

How do I go about populating the dropdown with the array?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using angular, you just use a loop on the options of your select (dropdown). Somethign like this:

```html
<select id="my-menu">
    <option *ngFor="let entry of myArray" value="entry.value">
    {{entry.text}}
    </option>
</select>
```